# Denying sending email

Tags: email

Here's the situation:

Person is denying sending an email.

I downloaded the original source file of the email which has all the digital signature details including IP address et al (in Gmail webmail show original)
I downloaded the same file of the denial email both IP and digital signatures match. This file is downloadable on both ends it's impossible for me to forge they need to match.

do I have a solid irrefutable evidence?

Comment: Even if you prove it come from their account on their computer it does not prove that specific person sent it, so irrefutable evidence? No. A reasonable level of confidence,  yes.

Comment: What do you call *digital signature details*? Was the mail signed with a PGP or X509 certificate?

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not have solid irrefutable evidence.  I could have stolen their password and sent the email from their account.

That being said, the key question you should ask yourself is how much proof do you need in the current environment.  If this is office politics, you may not need very much proof at all.  If you're trying to indite someone for selling state secrets, you're going to need a lot more proof.

Answer (score 0):

Did they send any files, malware or suspicious links?

Evidence is handled by a chain of command and should be held in a safe. Forensic copies should be made of the original and then further analysis can be performed. I'm new at forensics, but I am studying it (CHFI). For example, if there was malware that pointed to the same IP address as the offending email at some point, it would make a case.